# MySQL and PHP for Unique ID for a comment table that referres to something

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know if the title is exactly what I try to explain, my English skills are low. But I explain myself: I have a MySQL table to store comments for my news table:

```
news_comments:

id INT, AI
id_new INT
name VARCHAR
comment TEXT
```

But I want a unique number for each comment of each new. So for id_new=1, I have a #1, #2, #3... and id_new=2 another #1, #2, #3.

If I delete comment #1 from id_new=1, #2 will stay #2 and the next comment (if exists #2 and #3) will be #4. If #4 is deleted, new comment will be #5.

How I can manage this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: **Nope, you don't want it**. As a matter of fact, it's not a number at all. Just leave it alone

Comment: I agree with Col. Shrapnel. You are putting "logic" into your primary key which is almost always a bad idea. Why do you think you need to do that?

Comment: Why do you have id_new field? Does it relate to another table? Your id field will be unique in this case.

Comment: I don't know if I am explaining right, my English isn't good. I need a "sequential" number when I'm showing the comments. The users when comments referees to the other comments like "I like comment #5". So if you are doing a for/foreach that increments the number, if you delete #4, the #5 will be now the #4. You got the idea? Thank you!

Comment: Your english is good enough. Your goal is wrong. **You don't need a sequential number**. At least in that id field. If you want to enumerate your comments, you can do it at output time, using separate variable. While unique identifier should **remain unique**. Understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally your auto_increment field is also your primary key, but it doesn't have to be. You can make your primary key a compound index (more than one column). Then the auto increment will increment off of the first column, giving you what you are looking for. Your table doesn't contain an id to relate to the news item though, which you would need in order to do this.

```
CREATE TABLE news_comments (
news_id INT,
comment_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR, comment TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY commment_key (news_id, comment_id)
);
```

If the news_id is 1, then the comment_id will start incrementing off of that, and will start at 1 for each unique news_id.

Comment: +1: Why did people -2 your answer? That is the answer for MyISAM tables. Maybe you should change to use OP column names: `create table news_comments (id int auto_increment, id_new int, name varchar(255), comment text, primary key (id_new, id)) engine=myisam;`

Comment: Yes, it only works for MyISAM tables. I should have clarified that.

Answer (score 2):

First, store your unique numbers in a separate field from `id`. For instance, `uid INT` with a constraint that `UNIQUE(id_new, uid)`. `id` is and should remain an auto-incremented identifier field, because it will make your life easier down the line (you can access your comments with only one identifier instead of two, for instance).

The easiest thing to do is to keep the deleted comments around (with an `is_deleted` field), and use MAX() to find the largest identifier allocated so far for a given `is_new`.

Another possibility is to keep track of previously allocated `uid`s in your `news` table itself, but it involves more work and an additional update for every new comment.